# Install ODBC driver on Travis without sudo

Tags: odbc, travis-ci

I try use new container-based infrastructure on Travis.
But I have problem with install ODBC driver.
Now I use `sudo` to do this.

```
sudo: required

addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - unixodbc
      - unixodbc-dev
      - libmyodbc

before_install:
  - sudo odbcinst -i -d -f /usr/share/libmyodbc/odbcinst.ini
  - odbcinst -i -s -h -f ./test/mytest.odbc.ini
```

And this is only one place where I use `sudo`
I need create DSN to test because some API of my library can work only with it.

**Update:**
I also install `libsqliteodbc` and this library does not requiere call  `odbcinst`. It avaliable in system just right after `apt-get`.

Just in case [link to job](https://travis-ci.org/moteus/lua-odbc/jobs/109797247)

Comment: `sudo` -> normal infrastructure. No `sudo` -> container-based infrastructure. No way of going 'round that, TTBOMK.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, Travis won't let me see the job. I'm tryhing to install the SQL Server 13 ODBC drivers on Travis... could you pls post your whole travis.yml contents? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by copy `odbcinst.ini` file to `$HOME` dir.
I am not sure is it possible do with `odbcinst`.
Also I found that `libsqliteodbc` `odbc-postgresql` install it while call `apt-get install` and there no need any additional steps. But `libmyodbc` require also additional steps.